# Modificar hook de componente padre desde componente hijo

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una consulta sobre hooks. Como pueden ver en el siguiente código, hay un hook llamado ahook. Que se define en CompleteInfo pero que necesito que en el componente Child se modifique. ¿Es posible modifcar un hook de un componente padre desde un componente hijo?

En caso de no ser posible. ¿Cómo es posible implementar la modificación de un hook de un componente padre desde un componente hijo?

```
const CompleteInfo =  () => {

    const [ahook,setTheHook]=useState(0)
    
    /* other code*/
    
    
    if(ahook==0){
        return(<Child ahook={ahook}></Child>);
    }
    if(ahook==1){
        return(<Child2 ahook={ahook}></Child2>);
    }
   
   /*Más código*/    

}

const Child =  (ahook:any) => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  if (count < 10){
    return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
  }else{
    
    /*
      Aca necesito modificar el hook de CompleteInfo
    */
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

llámalo desde props y lo instancias por destructuring

```
const CompleteInfo =  () => {

    const [ahook,setTheHook]=useState(0)
    
    /* other code*/
    
    
    if(ahook==0){
        return(<Child ahook={ahook} setTheHook={setTheHook}></Child>);
    }
    if(ahook==1){
        return(<Child2 ahook={ahook}></Child2>);
    }
   
   /*Más código*/    

}

const Child =  (props) => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const {ahook, setTheHook} = props;
  
  if (count < 10){
    return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
  }else{
    
    /*
      Lo puedes instanciar normalmente como si fuera un componente del padre.
    */
  }

}
```

Comment: Gracias. Te hago una consulta, cuando instancio CompleteInfo y paso ahook, el valor cuando quiero utilizarlo en el componente Child es undefined. ¿Por qué se pasa como undefined?

Comment: Intenta colocar props en el componente padre también, se me pasó por alto y no lo hice const CompleteInfo = (props) = {}